# How to wrap Primeng TurboTable Component

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I want to wrap primeng Turbo Table component in my own component, but cant figure out how to use primeng pSortIcon and pSortableColumn directive in template which I'm passing to my custom component.

```
<my-table #tableCmp
                    [value]="val"
                    [columns]="columns"
                     sortMode="multiple"
                    [responsive]="true"
                    [paginator]="true"
                    [rows]="10"
                    [lazy]="true"
                    [totalRecords]="totalRecordsLen"
                    [pageLinks]="3"
                    (onLazyLoading)="lazyLoadData($event)"
                    (onSort)="onSort($event)">
                <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                  <tr>
                   <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
                     {{col.header}}
                     <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
                   </th>
                  </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
                  <tr>
                   <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{rowData[col.field]}}
                   </td>
                  </tr>
                 </ng-template>
  </my-table>
```

This is how I'm applying templates to my custom component:

```
@ContentChildren(PrimeTemplate) tpl: QueryList<PrimeTemplate>;

ngAfterContentInit() {
    const originalTableNgAfterContentInit = this.table.ngAfterContentInit;
    this.table.ngAfterContentInit = () => {
        this.table.tpl= this.tpl;
        originalTableNgAfterContentInit.call(this.table);
    };
}
```

When I use my custom component it gives me the following error:

> p-sortIcon/pSortableColumn is not a known element

In my module I've imported TableModule and I've checked that TableModule exports SortIcon and SortableColumn.

I'll be very thankfull if someone knows how to figure out my problem !

Comment: Did you figure anything out on this? I'm having the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the solution from this thread? https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=57029